# Chart - trendlines - slope - NDVI - visibleInLegend: true - GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, chart

I am using the following code in GEE to calculate the trend line:

```
ndviChart.setOptions({
    title: 'NDVI (Sentinel 2)',
    vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
    trendlines: {type: 'exponential', 0: {color: 'CC0000'}, visibleInLegend: true},
    hAxis: {title: 'Data', format: 'MM-YY', gridlines: {count: 7}},
  });
```

The above code generates the trendline formula as a legend in the chart:

```
nd = 73.163e^-1.151E-4*system:time_start
```

where the slope is indicated in the caption as 73.163e ^ -1.151E-4

How do I extract the subtitle slope and store this value in a variable?